Doing backpropagation in YOLOv8
I am trying to craft adversarial sample for YOLO-v8 model. Unfortunately, I do not get gradient in the predicted boxes. Here is my code in a nutsehll
images = resized_inp.clone().detach().to(torch.device('cuda'))
labels = gt_xyxyn.unsqueeze(0).to(torch.device('cuda'))
delta = torch.zeros_like(images).to(torch.device('cuda'))
delta.requires_grad = True
num_iter = 2
epsilon = 0.03
alpha = 1.0
for _ in range(num_iter):
    outputs = model(images + delta)[0].boxes.xyxyn
    loss = l1_loss(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    grad = delta.grad.detach()
    delta.data = delta + alpha * grad.sign()
    delta.data = torch.clamp(delta, -epsilon, epsilon)
    delta.data = torch.clamp(images + delta.data, 0, 1) - images
    delta.grad.zero_()

images is of shape [1, 3, 640, 640], as expected by YOLO-v8 segmentation model. labels contains normalized xyxy coordinate so it is of shape [1, 4].
loss is calculated fine, but when loss.backward() is called, it give error as:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 11
      9 outputs = model(images + delta)[0].boxes.xyxyn
     10 loss = l1_loss(outputs, labels)
---> 11 loss.backward()
     12 grad = delta.grad.detach()
     13 delta.data = delta + alpha * grad.sign()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py:522, in Tensor.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    512 if has_torch_function_unary(self):
    513     return handle_torch_function(
    514         Tensor.backward,
    515         (self,),
   (...)
    520         inputs=inputs,
    521     )
--> 522 torch.autograd.backward(
    523     self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
    524 )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:267, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    262     retain_graph = create_graph
    264 # The reason we repeat the same comment below is that
    265 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
...
    683     )  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    684 finally:
    685     if attach_logging_hooks:

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

This is happening because, although input has gradient turned on, the output does not have gradient. So my Question:

Is there a way to have gradient associated with these cordinates? Since they are torch tensors, I am hopeful to have it.
Is there any other way to craft a PGD adversarial sample? I would ultimately like to run auto LiRPA on it.

